# How to format the date in Google Sheets using Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to create custom reports in Google Sheets. The data that I am putting in Google Sheets is coming from JSON data that I am parsing in. One of my columns contains a date and time string from the JSON and I want to format it so Google Sheets recognizes it as a date and time rather than a string.

Currently, the string displays as the following in Google Sheets:

```
2019-06-10T22:00:00.000Z
```

I am not sure how to change the format so it looks like a proper date and time.

Edit: I would like it to look something like:

```
10-Jun HH-MM
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Requirement:

Format date string in Google Apps Script.

---

#### Solution:

Pass date string to date constructor `new Date()` then use `Utilities.formatDate` to format it correctly.

---

#### Example:

```
function convertDate() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var date = sh.getRange(1,1).getValue(); //this is your value '2019-06-10T22:00:00.000Z'
  var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date),'GMT+0','dd-MMM HH-mm');
  Logger.log(d);
  //logger returns: 10-Jun 22-00
}
```

---

#### References:

1. [`new Date()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) for date constructor.
2. [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) for formatting dates in Google Apps Script.